# Ventanas modales con los resultados de php

Tags: php, html

Buen día, necesito saber si hay alguna manera de hacer que con los resultados de php se creen ventanas modales (una por cada resultado) y botones que abran la correspondiente, lo he intentado en diversas ocasiones, pero me resultó como una sobrecarga para el sitio, porque al recibir un resultado hacía echo  , los botones con el atributo open abrían la modal con el id modal1, lo que también resultaba poco profesional. Necesitaría ayuda con eso, no tengo un código, pero si se me entiende que es lo que quiero hacer, un boceto o alguna explicación me vendría de lujo, gracias!

Comment: Puedes crear un solo modal donde se estén cargando los datos dinamicamente con JQuery y cada que abres ese modal estas limpiándolo y insertando los datos de lo que te interesa mostrar.

Comment: @EduardoJavierMaldonado Si, lo estuve pensando pero a cada botón le tendría que asignar una id de lo que quiero consultar en php, y eso es lo que me complica, gracias.